# How to output all lines of a file without the last line?

Tags: unix, shell, text

What is the best way to output all lines of a file without the last line, using command-line tools?

Example:

```
$ cat foo.txt
a b c
v w x y z
a sd dsgdfg 

$ some-cmd foo.txt
a b c
v w x y z
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BASH, using `head`:

```
$ head --lines=-1 filename
```

Same for Mac:

```
expr "$a" : '\(.*\)
'
```

The newline is required!

Comment: 1. This has absolutely nothing to do with bash. 2. It doesn't work in Mac OS :(

Comment: 1. It has *something* to do with bash - you can execute that process with bash.

Comment: Right, I was exaggerating ;) Any idea how to do this on Mac?

Answer (score 5):

Probably the shortest way:

```
sed '$d' filename
```

Comment: See also: http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?delete+last+line (yes, sed is the shortest there) :)

Comment: oh, and `sed \$d filename` is shorter (bash/zsh/fish entries on golf.shinh have 7 bytes, they're obviously doing `sed \$d`)